# Wake up ESP32 deep sleep when sensor value is below threshold

Tags: arduino, esp32, sensors, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

I have a capacitive soil moisture sensor and an ESP32 and I'm trying to get the ESP32 to stay in deep sleep until the soil moisture outputs a value that is below a certain threshold.

But I'm not quite sure if that is even possible. To have the soil moisture sensor work even while the ESP32 is in deep sleep.

I looked into external triggers to wake up the ESP32 but they seem to involve buttons mostly not sensors that should output a value every x seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think you can achieve that with a "dumb" sensor like the moisture sensor. In very very simple terms they need to be pushed from the ESP to get their reading which means the ESP has to be awake.

I guess you want this to run of a battery juice hence the deep sleep.

There are couple of ways you could do it:

1. Wake up the ESP on a timer maybe every 1 hour or so, take the reading and act if you need to. To save more power disable the WiFi/Bluetooth radios first as they will draw a lot on the wake up.

   WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
   btStop();

If you then need to do something over WiFi/BL then start it, send what you need, switch the radios off again and go to sleep.

To be honest, if you don't need bluetooth you could use an ESP8266 as it needs less power anyway than an ESP32

I have few setups like that and they work fine

2. This is a bit more involved option but could probably give more life of a battery.
   The idea is to use a very small secondary microcontroller that needs very little power and is capable just enough to take the readings and if required it can be used to power up the ESP when needed. Maybe something like a Attiny11 could do the job?

Basically that secondary controller would act as a power relay for the ESP, so when the secondary detects low moisture through the sensor it powers up the ESP. The ESP doesn't even have to be attached to the sensor, it can get the readings from that secondary controller when it powers up and when it does its job it can send an instruction to the secondary to turn its power off (ESP power off I mean)

Of course this is a very generalised description, you would probably need few more things like a voltage regulator etc.

Actually, I need to get off my ass and build something like that at some point for my veggie planter, I wonder if I can get it to run off a little solar panel? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with answer given by @chipchop-gizmo, I'd like to add some more suggestions based on my experience with the ESP32 and low power.

Starting with: ESP32 is really bad at low power. Because of its high CPU frequency and even more so because of its high-power radio, it will drain your batteries very fast. (Compared to some low-power controllers).

The most efficient solution is the one mentioned in the other answer. That you should use a secondary, very low-power controller to handle everything else and leave the ESP32 to only communicate when necessary.

It could be the case that you are planning on selling your device at a commercial scale and adding a second controller could simply raise the cost too much, or you don't want the headache of maintaining two different software and testing them and keeping them compatible with each other while you upgrade one and then the other over time.

If you absolutely have to stick to Espressif (we all love a cheap, all-purpose, and easy to use controller) and you don't want to use a second controller, then you'd wanna switch to the single core ESP32-C3, and turn its CPU frequency all the way down. And if you can use BLE instead of WiFi, it'd save you some more power.

Still, the lowest you can get in deep sleep is around 20 uA which might sound really good, but it all goes to waste the moment ESP32 wakes up with its 100mA current draw. So for deep sleep to have any good effect you'd have to place your timed wakeups far apart and have plenty of deep sleep in between.

After waking up, you'd wanna do **ALL** of the algorithm / computation / data acquisition **before** you turn on the radio. The CPU by itself uses around 15 mA of current. Once everything is ready to be transmitted, turn on the WiFi/BLE and transmit as little data as possible. With radio on it consumes 80+ mA. After transmission, put it immediately in deep sleep.

ESP32 allows deep-sleep wakeup from both GPIO interrupts and timer based interrupt. And it also provides a function that tells you if the last wakeup was from a GPIO or a timer. So using these with a state machine can create some pretty nifty applications.

### Alternative

If at all, you can let go of WiFi and switch to a controller from Nordic Semi, like the nRF52832, you'd be surprised at how much power you can squeeze out of even the tiniest batteries.

Here's a comparison of their current consumptions

| State | ESP32 | nRF52 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Deep Sleep | 20 uA | 800 nA |
| Light Sleep | 2 mA | 3 uA |
| CPU on | 15 mA | 2 mA |
| Radio on | 80 mA | 7 mA |
| ADC reading | 80 mA | 1 mA |
| i2c reading | 50 mA | 2 mA |

In one of my low-power applications, the same algorithm and hardware which would give me barely 10 months of battery life on an ESP32, gave me around 5 years of battery life on an nRF52832.

If you application can afford an nRF chip, trust me you'd love it.

(This answer has not been sponsored by Nordic Semi :p)